# Angular HttpClient does not send request

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am in the process of developing an Angular frontend application for my .NET 7 backend WebApi, and I have encountered a strange issue that I cannot find the proper solution or root-cause for. The code you see below is within a Service class in my Angular project.

```
public getCompanies(): Observable<Company[]> {
    return this.http.get<AllCompaniesQueryResult>('https://localhost:7234/api/companies').pipe(
      map((x) => x.companies as unknown as Company[]),
      tap((x) => this.companies.next(x)),
    );
}
```

Sometimes this function works as intended and I get the result that I wish for. But now suddenly I can no longer get it to work. When I look into the Network tab in the DevTools of my browser (I have tried Chrome and Firefox Dev Edition) I don't see any trafic going towards the WebApi. Keep in mind this has worked and suddenly without me changing anything, that should have an effcet on this, it has stopped working.

It first started when I changed the URL from the hardcoded url to this:

```
`${apiBaseUrl}/${API.COMPANIES}`
```

I have checked in the console by printing it that it is indeed the correct URL. I have click the url and I get the correct response in my browser, but the HttpClient in Angular does not seem to send the request.

When I investigate the HttpClients request function I can see that in this line:

```
const res$ = events$.pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof HttpResponse));
```

my browser tells me that `events$.pipe` is undefined.

Before anyone tells me that I need to `subscribe()` I have tried be following code below as well:

```
public getCompaniesV2(): void {
    this.http.get<AllCompaniesQueryResult>('https://localhost:7234/api/Companies').subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log('Entered next()');
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('Entered error()');
        console.log(err);
      },
    });
  }
```

In this function I don't get any output in the console on my `console.log()`'s.

I really hope that there is someone that can help me out with this issue.

Lastly I have been looking into some of the other questions that relates to this, but I have not tried everything trick that I was able to find online.

**UPDATE**

It might add that it could have something to do with the WebApi even through I doubt it. I have not changed anything in the WebApi from when it worked until it stopped working.

Comment: are there maybe some CORS issues?

Comment: I have configured the WebApi to Allow any origin, method and header. I would assume that the console would provide me with the error if that was the case.

Comment: Mh, okay ... are there some httpInterceptos in the project that might swallow the requests?

Comment: No there isn't any...

Comment: You said you tried `getCompaniesV2()`, but where? Are you sure this is gets executed in first place? Where do you call `getCompaniesV2()` and `getCompanies()` ?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I have put in a ```console.log('test')``` before the return statement, and I got the output in the console. The functions get executed for sure.